# Why android documentation refers to density with dpi instead of ppi?

Tags: android

I'm reading (once again) the [documentation about the supported screen densities](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

And I wonder why density is referred in terms of dpi (dots per inch) instead of ppi (pixels per inch).

First I though these would be synonymous, but I did some research, and dpi seems to be associated with printers, colors/ink and stuff and I think what the Android documentation means should be ppi. Am I correct?

Note: I'm not talking about dip or dp, which is something completly different.

Comment: dpi *is* the same as ppi

Comment: In the Android docs apparently yes, but not elsewhere. Try: https://www.google.com/search?q=difference+dpi+ppi&oq=difference+dpi+ppi&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i65j0j69i60j0l2.5269j0&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Nexus 5 tech specs use PPI - http://www.google.com/nexus/5/

Comment: @FranciPenov I'm talking about Android documentation, not device's specs.

Comment: I understand that. I was merely showing that Google itself is not consistent about the usage of the two terms, and I suspect @Ahmad is correct that they should be treated the same within the context of Android dev docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the docs state clearly:

"Screen density The quantity of pixels within a physical area of the screen; usually referred to as dpi (dots per inch). For example, a "low" density screen has fewer pixels within a given physical area, compared to a "normal" or "high" density screen."

So I think it's just vocabulary choice, because they mean actually ppi.